# getInnerHeight and getInnerWidth in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are using `getInnerHeight` and `getInnerWidth` methods in our application.Now we are migrating to `ExtJS4`. As per my Observation, these two methods are not there for `panel`.

Is there any thing replaces these two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using innerHeight and innerWidth? You can get the height/width of the element that the `Ext.Panel` is rendered to as follows...

```
var height = Ext.getCmp('panelId').getEl().getHeight();
```

This should suffice unless you've got massive amounts of padding on your panel.

Comment: Thank a lot for your quick reply.But i am trying to get the height of the body element(not including the height of any framing elements).Using getInnerHeight we can do in ExtJS3. But now those methods are not there.

Comment: But a panel is just a div basically, if you inspect the markup you'll notice there is barely no difference whatsoever (if any) between getHeight() and getInnerHeight()

Answer (score 1):

if you need the body width/height(without header, dockeditems etc...)try this:

```
var height = Ext.getCmp('panelId').body.getHeight(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass boolean true as parameter for the getHeight() function. So you get:

```
var height = Ext.getCmp('panelId').getEl().getHeight(true);
```